# bazaar checkout error

Tags: bazaar

I am in folder where I have rwx rights
and I tried this

`bzr branch bzr+ssh://bazaar.launchpad.net/%2Bbranch/openobject-addons/7.0/`

I gave 'yes' when they asked to store public key

But the following error message occured

`Permission denied (publickey).
ConnectionReset reading response for 'BzrDir.open_2.1', retrying
Permission denied (publickey).
bzr: ERROR: Connection closed: Unexpected end of message. Please check connectivity and permissions, and report a bug if problems persist.

Its a public repo, So there shouldn't be any access right problems.
Is there a problem with the link? How do I verify this?
`

Answer (score 5):

This can happen if your launchpad user is not setup correctly in Bazaar. Check the output of:

```
bzr lp-login
```

If the output is not your launchpad user OR it is but your ssh key is not authorized, then that will cause the problem you are having.
Fix your username and upload the correct ssh public key.

**Explanation**

Launchpad tries to authenticate even read-only operations IF you have told Bazaar *a* Launchpad username, for example:

```
$ bzr lp-login jelmer
$ bzr info lp:bzr
Permission denied (publickey).
ConnectionReset reading response for 'BzrDir.open_2.1', retrying
Permission denied (publickey).
bzr: ERROR: Connection closed: Unexpected end of message. Please check connectivity and permissions, and report a bug if problems persist.
```

"Permission denied", because I am NOT `jelmer`, and he certainly did not authorize my key.

So first check the Launchpad username you told Bazaar and change it if it's not you, for example:

```
$ bzr lp-login  # ain't gonna be me...
jelmer
$ bzr lp-login janos-gyerik  # yeah that's me!
```

If it's the correct username, then visit your settings page on Launchpad and make sure your public key is listed there: https://launchpad.net/~YOUR_USERNAME

Or, you could remove your Launchpad username setting with this command:

```
bzr config --remove launchpad_username --scope bazaar
```

However, when you run `bzr` commands on Launchpad branches you will get a warning if you haven't set a Launchpad username. (Which is ok, you can just ignore it if you don't want to write to Launchpad.)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to branch it fine now with your command, maybe the version of bazaar that you are using is too old.
Another thing that is sometimes a problem is corporate firewalls that don't allow ssh out.

Comment: My version is Bazaar 2.5.1.Isn't the latest?
So the only remaining reason is corporate firewalls ?

Comment: ok I looked at your error again and it seems that launchpad doesn't like your key. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/144839/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-start-working-with-launchpad-again-on-a-new-computer

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue using a custom SSH key for Launchpad. I resolved it by adding the following lines to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host bazaar.launchpad.net
    IdentityFile  /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa_launchpad
    User launchpad-username
```

Ref: https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/CreatingAnSSHKeyPair#Using_a_custom_SSH_key_for_Launchpad

Answer (score 0):

If you're behind a proxy, you'd need SSH via tunneling (using corkscrew).
I had the same problem, and doing the following steps solved my error:

- Install corkscrew on your machine
- Add the following lines to `~/.ssh/config`

  ```
  Host bazaar.launchpad.net
      User <launchpad-username>
      ProxyCommand corkscrew <proxy-address> <proxy-port> %h %p
  ```

Answer (score -1):

I had this mistake when I tried to create SSH key by means of the program
puttygen.exe . Everything turned out when I created SSH key as is specified according to the link https://askubuntu.com/a/144858 . Thanks.